# How to make a flat not solid border using css?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a flat border like this one,
[image]

It not should be like this one:

```css
.demo{
  height: 60px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #007bff #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo"></div>
```

I think it was made by CSS before/ after. But Remember that It actually not made by using border property.
I need the same things like this photo. I have no idea that how to made it. **[Q1]** Is I need many span or before after width? (Please give a simple design)

**[Q2]** How WordPress make their article title box? are they used before/after or many span elm? (I already inspect WordPress editor but nothing find)

Comment: share you code here

Comment: flat border means do you want very thin border line? if you want thin border just change `border-width` to `1px`

Comment: Thin or fat is not the matter, I need a perfect stret border like this photo.

Comment: hey @MdAlex, please use border width property as like this -  `border-width: 1px 1px 1px 5px;`.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.demo {
  height: 60px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  position: relative;
  border-left: 4px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.demo::after {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its a little hack with `:before` property:

```
.demo{
    border-left: solid 5px black;
    width: 90%;
    height: 50px;
    position:relative;
}
.demo:before{
    content:"";
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position:absolute;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-left:none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Or another way you can achieve like this:

HTML

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="left-pad"></div>
  <div class="demo"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.card {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.left-pad {
  width: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.demo{
    border: solid 1px gray;
    border-left: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

May be it helps

Answer (score 0):

Gradient can do it. Simply adjust the order to control which one will be on the top

```css
.demo{
  height: 60px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#007bff,#007bff) left   /5px 100%, /* The top layer */
    linear-gradient(red,red)         right  /5px 100%,
    linear-gradient(#ddd,#ddd)       bottom /100% 2px,
    linear-gradient(blue,blue)       top    /100% 2px; /* The bottom layer */
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this :- display: table;

```
.demo {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 2em auto;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid #b6bdc2;
    width: 90%;
    height: 60px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-left-width: 4px;
    border-left-color: #5d646c;
}


<div class="demo">
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

May be it helps